# Import module, that import another module. Python

Tags: python, python-import

I was curious what happens when we import a module that in turn imports another module. So I create two modules: module1 and module2.

module1:

```
import random
print(random.randint(0,10))
print("module1 work")
```

module2:

```
import module1
print("module2 work")
```

When I run module2 it give me this output:

```
1
module1 work
module2 work
```

So, I decided that I did indeed import `random`, when I imported `module1`. But when I type in the Shell `print(random.randint(0,10))`it throws a `NameError: name 'random' is not defined`. So `random` wasn't imported from `module1`. But in this case why did `module2` print `1`, and didn't throw the same error as the Shell?

Comment: Just because a module has been executed doesn't necessarily mean the `module` object is bound to a name in the global namespace. Try `module1.random.randint(0,10)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each module has its own scope (or namespace, if that terminology is more familiar to you). If you want to access `random` from `module2`, you need to import it in `module2`. The interpreter shares the scope of the module you execute, so only variables declared in the global namespace of that module will be accessible. If you want to access `random` from the interpreter having only imported `module2`, you'll need to specify `module1.random`.

Alternatively, you can replace `import module1` with `from module1 import *`. That will copy over everything, including the reference to `random`. So `random` will be accessible globally.

Comment: or you could do `print(module1.random.randint(0,10))`, if you don't want to import random in module2

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are not actually importing random into the shell, instead just the file that contains the module.

We can use an existing module as an example, for example tkinter which opens with:

```
import enum
import sys
```

They import into the Tkinter module but when you import Tkinter they don't come with it.

To put it is as simply as possible your `module1` has random imported, but imporing `module1` will not also import `random`